# HAProxy is not working with SNI and ACLs

Tags: linux, haproxy, sni

I am trying to get haproxy to use acls with SNI and it ain't cooperating. It  presents the correct cert so SNI must be working. However, I cannot get it to select a backend based on the hostname in SNI.

Which I check the configuration, I get the following

```
[WARNING]  (21486) : Proxy 'fe-dr-totalflood.com': L6 sample fetches ignored on HTTP proxies (declared at ./haproxy.cfg.tmp:176).
[WARNING]  (21486) : Proxy 'fe-dr-totalflood.com': L6 sample fetches ignored on HTTP proxies (declared at ./haproxy.cfg.tmp:177).
Warnings were found.
Configuration file is valid
```

I have no idea what the error messages mean and I've put a note next to the corresponding lines in the following snippet.

```
frontend  fe-dr-totalflood.com
  mode      http
  bind      172.22.8.229:80
  bind      172.22.8.229:443 ssl crt dr-www.totalflood.com.crt crt dr-xml.totalflood.com.crt

  ## http->https redirect
  http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }

  ## access control lists
  acl https ssl_fc
  acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
  acl www-acl req_ssl_sni dr-www.totalflood.com
  acl xml-acl req_ssl_sni dr-xml.totalflood.com

  # if Let's Encrypt, skip remainder and jump to the backend
  use_backend be-letsencrypt if letsencrypt-acl

  use_backend be-dr-www.totalflood.com if www-acl <------ 176
  use_backend be-dr-xml.totalflood.com if xml-acl <------ 177

  default_backend be-no-such-site

#------------------------------------------------
backend   be-dr-www.totalflood.com
  mode      http
  balance   roundrobin
  cookie    SERVERID insert indirect nocache maxidle 30m

  ## set the host name in the header
  acl h_host_exists req.hdr(Host) -m found
  http-request del-header Host if h_host_exists
  http-request set-header Host www.totalflood.com

  default-server check maxconn 100

  server  scadmzp2wb01 scadmzp2wb01.lereta.net:80 cookie scadmzp2wb01

#------------------------------------------------
backend   be-dr-xml.totalflood.com
  mode      http
  balance   roundrobin
  cookie    SERVERID insert indirect nocache maxidle 30m

  ## set the host name in the header
  acl h_host_exists req.hdr(Host) -m found
  http-request del-header Host if h_host_exists
  http-request set-header Host xml.totalflood.com

  default-server check maxconn 100

  server  scadmzxml01 scadmzxml01.lereta.net:80 cookie scadmzxml01

#------------------------------------------------
backend be-letsencrypt
  server localhost 127.0.0.1:8888

#------------------------------------------------
backend be-no-such-site
  server localhost 127.0.0.1:8888
```

When I try to access either site I always hit the default backend no matter what.  I've tested this by changing the default backend to go other places. If I
append to either url the /.well-known/acme-challenge path, haproxy seems to send me to the correct place.

What I cannot figure out is why the acls based on SNI information don't work.

I am using version 2.4.2 of haproxy OracleLinux 8.

```
$ haproxy -v
HAProxy version 2.4.2-553dee3 2021/07/07 - https://haproxy.org/
Status: long-term supported branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q2 2026.
Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.4.2.html
Running on: Linux 5.4.17-2136.304.4.1.el8uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Tue Feb 8 11:54:24 PST 2022 x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the docs:

> Fetching samples from buffer contents is a bit different from the previous
> sample fetches above because the sampled data are ephemeral. These data can
> only be used when they're available and will be lost when they're forwarded.
> For this reason, samples fetched from buffer contents during a request cannot
> be used in a response for example. Even while the data are being fetched, they
> can change.

That's why you get a warning about ignoring Layer 6 ACLs.

Instead of using `req_ssl_sni`, you had better use `ssl_fc_sni` at Layer 5, which will get you the same information but more reliably.

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, good solution !